# Browsers load page really slow

Tags: caching, networking, browser

Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (6.1, Build 7600) (7600.win7_rtm.090713-1255)
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.9GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3584MB RAM
          Page File: 1671MB used, 5493MB available
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7600.16385 32bit Unicode

Hello, that is part of my dxdiag, I can send the rest if needed. My problem is nomatter what I do, clear cache, cookies, empty TEMP and PREFETCH folders, used CC Cleaner, upgraded internet speed to 3mbps, made sure I have little-to-no browser addons or plugins, my browsers load any websites I visit really slow, normally would take 8 seconds to load. What could be wrong? Why can't I have a fast loading browser like in net cafes? I use Chrome and FF by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing your cache and cookies can inadvertanly cause websites you visit frequently to load slower.  The cache is used to to store information that is accessed frequently so that it doesn't have to be downloaded to your machine every single time you refresh a webpage or reload your browser.

While your system specifications are fine, it may not be your machine causing the lag you're experiencing.  For example, despite upgrading your internet connection, are you behind a router, firewall, or proxy that is filtering everything?

Your Internet service provider could be throttling your connection (along with many others) during peak times that your most frequently using the web.  Other issues, which in some instances might be the case (but likely isn't) is that the content you're trying to connect to is far away.

You should try using a browser alternative to the one you always use. For example if you use Firefox all the time, you might try using Chrome.  If websites are still slow, this could point to an issue other than your computer, be it your home network or service provider.